# How do you configure JBoss to trim additional whitespaces generated by JSPs?

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, whitespace, trim

Getting lots of additional whitespace in the html output, looks like its because of the JSP tags =/

I saw this referenced somewhere:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

That should put it in `web.xml`, I tried that but that didn't seem to work. Maybe I'm not putting it in the right node. Or maybe theres another way to do this.

Thanks

*I dont have the CATALINA_HOME var set anywhere.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mentioned `<init-param>` should be added to the "jsp" servlet in `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml`. Is this what you tried?

(EDIT: $CATALINA_HOME was just a way to designate the root of Tomcat and that the modification had to be done in Tomcat, not in the `WEB-ING/web.xml` of your webapp. Anyhow, for JBoss **which is embedding Tomcat**, and depending on the version you are using, you'll find the mentioned file here: `$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy/jbossweb-tomcat55.sar/conf/web.xml`. Here again, $JBOSS_HOME is the root of your JBoss installation, it may not be set as environment variable.)

Comment: +1: that's the right place. Not the WEB-INF/web.xml of your webapp.

Comment: I don't think this is using Tomcat I dont have the CATALINA_HOME var set anywhere.

Comment: The `web.xml` is place in different places in different JBoss versions. For JBoss 5.1 you can find it here: `$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/web.xml`, for JBoss 6: `$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/web.xml`

Answer (score 5):

After some digging around, i found the procedure for JBoss AS 7. If anyone is interested: in your standalone.xml, find the section

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:  ... >
```

And add this directive:

```
<configuration>
    <jsp-configuration trim-spaces="true" />
</configuration>
```

[Here are other attributes you may use](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/jsp.html)